# JS not working in FireFox but works in Chrome & I.E

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know there are question like this but I still can't find a fix, I've looked through the console and can't see anything. There are two images, one which should appear on set coordinates, and another which follows the mouse, the one which is mean't to follow the mouse does not show up but the other one does.

Main.js

```
/**
* Created with JetBrains WebStorm.
* User: Script47
* Date: 22/09/13
* Time: 00:54
*/

function drawAvatars() {

// Create variable for the canvas & create a new object for image
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var userImage = new Image();

// The source of the images
userImage.src = ("Images/userImage.png");

// Create an event listener then call function redrawAvatar
gameCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", redrawAvatar);
}

function redrawAvatar(mouseEvent) {

var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var userImage = new Image();
var enemyImage = new Image();
var score = 0;

userImage.src = ("Images/userImage.png");
enemyImage.src = ("Images/enemyImage.png");

// Erase canvas sort of refresh, then re-draw image following the coordinates of the mouse in the canvas
gameCanvas.width = 400;
gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(userImage, mouseEvent.offsetX, mouseEvent.offsetY);
gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(enemyImage, 150, 150);

// Simple hit detection to see if user image hits enemy image
if (mouseEvent.offsetX > 130 && mouseEvent.offsetX < 175 && mouseEvent.offsetY > 130 && mouseEvent.offsetY < 175) {
    score++;
    alert("You hit the enemy!\n You score is: " +score);
}
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Avoid Me | Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
<script src="JS/Main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<br/>

<center><h3>Avoid Me!</h3>

<br/>
<br/>

<canvas id="gameCanvas" height="300" width="400" onclick="drawAvatars();">
    <p><strong>Notice:</strong> Browser does not support canvas!</p>
</canvas>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK9SP/)

Comment: a Fiddle will be more than enough..

Comment: a fiddle would indeed help a lot

Comment: Open FireFox then go to this URL: http://script47.tk/temp/Avoid%20Me!/

Comment: It doesn't really work for me in Chrome either :-) Can you check it?

Comment: @kobigurk, This is the error I get in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'src' of object #<HTMLImageElement> is not a function

Comment: Use enemyImage.src = "Images/enemyImage.png"; instead of 

enemyImage.src("Images/enemyImage.png");

For firefox, use pageX, and pageY, offset positions will work for chrome not for firefox (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

(Basing this off the code in the link you provided.)

In your mouseMovement function, you use mouseEvent.offsetX and mouseEvent.offsetY to get the player's position, but Firefox unfortunately doesn't support those properties. Unfortunately, IIRC, the only thing that works cross-browser is to get the position of the canvas, and subtract it from the event's pageX/pageY properties. You can use the canvas's getBoundingClientRect() method to find its position on the page.

This is is an example of a version of the function that should work in Firefox as well:

```
function mouseMovement(mouseEvent) {
    var canvasPosition = gameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    userImageX = mouseEvent.pageX - canvasPosition.left;
    userImageY = mouseEvent.pageY - canvasPosition.top;
}
```